# How can I run SpecFlow from the command line on Mono?

Tags: c#, mono, specflow

I have a simple C# app that I'd like to drive from SpecFlow acceptance tests.

The app and its scenarios have to be written, built and run from Mono.

I have to work with a simple text editor (not an IDE) and the command line.

The main problem seems to be generating the 'code behind' the feature files. I know that you can do this from MonoDevelop, but I can't use MonoDevelop (at least not directly). Can I invoke MonoDevelop from the command line to generate the 'code behind'?

Has anyone got any pointers/instructions that might help?

Answer (score 0):

SpecFlow [has instructions for running SpecFlow.exe from the command line](https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/wiki/Tools).

Basically the command is

```
specflow.exe generateall <projectFile>
```

eg:

```
specflow.exe generateall BookShop.AcceptanceTests.csproj
```

the page doesn't say if the command in windows only or works on *nix, so you'll need to try it and see.

** EDIT **

This is a stripped down project file from my current project with all non specflow related stuff removed. It might serve as a starting point:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="12.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{AF546F23-38E9-45CF-8F61-83667F708C39}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>YourNAmespace</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>YourAssemblyName</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5.1</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <SccProjectName>SAK</SccProjectName>
    <SccLocalPath>SAK</SccLocalPath>
    <SccAuxPath>SAK</SccAuxPath>
    <SccProvider>SAK</SccProvider>
    <TargetFrameworkProfile />
    <SolutionDir Condition="$(SolutionDir) == '' Or $(SolutionDir) == '*Undefined*'">..\</SolutionDir>
    <RestorePackages>true</RestorePackages>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <Prefer32Bit>false</Prefer32Bit>
    <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <Prefer32Bit>false</Prefer32Bit>
    <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Configuration" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
    <Reference Include="TechTalk.SpecFlow">
      <HintPath>..\packages\SpecFlow.1.9.0\lib\net35\TechTalk.SpecFlow.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Features\TheFeature.feature.cs">
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
      <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
      <DependentUpon>TheFeature.feature</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="Features\TheFeature.feature">
      <Generator>SpecFlowSingleFileGenerator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>TheFeature.feature.cs</LastGenOutput>
    </None>
    <None Include="packages.config" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup />
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
  <Import Project="$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\nuget.targets" />
</Project>
```

Comment: Given that SpecFlow is for .NET and the command ends in ".exe" it's safe to assume Windows.

Comment: I've got as far as running SpecFlow.exe under Mono, but it needs a project file as argument for generateAll. Any ideas how to generate a minimal project file?

Comment: I've added a stab at what you might need @SebRose, but not sure if it will work.